# Recursively setting a TypeScript type not read-only without clobbering tuples

Tags: typescript

```
export type DraftObject<T> = {-readonly [P in keyof T]: Draft<T[P]>}
export interface DraftArray<T> extends Array<Draft<T>> {}
export type Draft<T> = T extends any[]
    ? DraftArray<T[number]>
    : T extends ReadonlyArray<any>
        ? DraftArray<T[number]>
    : T extends object ? DraftObject<T> : T


type tup = [number, number, number, number]

const T: Draft<tup> = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const U: tup = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const TT: tup = T
const UU: Draft<tup> = U
```

The type DraftObject should return any type with all its properties marked not read-only. This works in all cases, except tuple types, where they're incorrectly turned into arrays. How can I special case tuples, and `Readonly<>` them instead of making them `DraftArray`s?

Comment: FYI there is currently (in TS3.1) [no such thing as readonly tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26864).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jcalz said, there are no readonly tuples as of TypeScript 3.1.  If you want to make everything mutable, you can just use:

```
export type Draft<T> = {-readonly [P in keyof T]: Draft<T[P]>};
```

taking advantage of the [mapped tuples and arrays](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) added in TypeScript 3.1 and the previously existing special case for homomorphic mapped types applied to primitives (`Draft<T>` evaluates to `T` when `T` is primitive).

Answer (score 3):

If, for some reason, you need to detect the difference between tuples and arrays, you can use the fact that tuple types have a known `"0"` key (the string value, not the number `0`) but arrays do not:

```
type IfTuple<T extends any[], Y=true, N=false> = "0" extends keyof T ? Y : N

type TestTuple = IfTuple<[string, number], "tuple", "array">; // "tuple"
type TestArray = IfTuple<string[], "tuple", "array">; // "array"
```

This should be enough to build a conditional type that does something different for tuples from what it does for general arrays.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is very useful, but I've accepted the other answer since it was more relevant to my particular scenario. Thank you!